# XMonad - How to make a window appear on more than one physical screens?

Tags: window, screen, xmonad

As the title said, I need to show a window on two or more screens.

I tried `XMonad.Actions.CopyWindow`. But it seems although the window is copied to a correct workspace, it shows on only on one physical screen.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the problem, you simply cannot. One window is only visible once. By copying the window, you make it available to multiple workspaces, but it will only be displayed once. If you have only one monitor, e.g. the laptop screen, this will create the illusion that the window is everywhere. Even more so, if you float it and thereby keep the position fixed.

However, one window is displayed only once at a time.

You could mirror the whole desktop to all displays. If you have a laptop attached to a beamer, this might make sense. Then both physical displays will show the same windows.